# Is this function continuous at the origin

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I have just started learning to use the two-path test to find limits and I am very doubtful of my ability so I am verifying what I have done below is correct.

[image]

I first tried letting y=0 and x -> 0 then x=0 and y -> 0 
which gave the answers of limit 1 and -1  (I am not too confident this is correct) but I did this because when you approach sin from negative side the value it gives is negative.

Unsure of whether I got the parameters right, I tried doing y=x then y=-x while x->0
to get:
0, 1

Once again I am not sure whether I calculated the limits properly or chose the right parameters..Any ideas if this is the right way?

If I can use two-path test to prove limit does not exist then the function won't be continuous at the origin.

Comment: It might be helpful to note that $\lim_{h \to 0 } \frac{\sin h} {h}  = 1$, so $\sin h \approx h$ for small $h$. That is, try checking if $\frac{x-y}{|x|+|y|}$ is continuous at the origin first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. Simply saying that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}f(x,0)=1 \not= -1 = \lim\limits_{y\to 0^+}f(0,y)$ shows that your function can't be continuous at $(0,0)$. But you could also use $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}f(x,0)=1 \not= 0=f(0,0)$ to show that. Note however that the first counterexample is actually stronger since it tells you that no matter what value you give to $f(0,0)$, your function won't be continuous.

Comment: But $\lim_{x\to0}f(x,0)$ is *not* $0$, in fact, this limit does not exist.

Comment: @Andres Caicedo Hence the $+$ in $0^+$.

Comment: Well, the $+$ was not there at first. Thanks for fixing it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x,x) = 0$ for $x\ne 0$

$f(2x,x) = \frac{sin(x)}{3|x|}$ for $x\ne 0$

So approaching $(0,0)$ on $(x,x)$ path will give you limit $0$ and on $(2x,x)$ path (for $x>0$) will give you limit $\frac{1}{3}$. Therefore the function cannot be continuous in $(0,0)$.

Comment: can you please tell me how you always find the points to choose? When I look at a function I cannot often tell what its domain is so I just try random values to see which one will work..

Comment: Well you usually try $y=\alpha x$ and $x=0$ to get all the lines and then if it doesn't work, you try non-linear things such as $y=x^2$ and if that doesn't work, you start thinking about proving it's continuous.